# Twitter Bootstrap .navbar-fixed-top overlapping site when dynamic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, overlapping

The bootstrap site says *"Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the . Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS."*

And I did that, but my navbar has a text that is completely dynamic and can be a little big, so even if I add 100px padding, there is times when the navbar overlaps the div below.

Anybody know something I can do about it?

Thanks,

Vinicius

Answer (score 0):

Cause your text is dynamic you could set your padding dynamic too may be? If your long text is wrapped in a p or div with id "description" you could use:

```
$('body').css('padding-top',(60+$('#description').height())+"px");
```

Use this jquery in your document ready. Note this solution is not responsive.